# Load table css when the page start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change row background and font color of the table when the page start. How to do that? Currently, I only had done it in mouseout event.

```js
$("#tableGrid").ready(function(){

});

$("#tableGrid").on("mouseout","tr", function() {
  if($(this).children("td:eq(15)").text() == "CREATED") {
    $(this).children("td").css('background', '#fffff9');
    $(this).children("td").css('color', '#000000');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bal-main-conatiner bal-table booking-table' id="tableGrid"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your **HTML** code

Comment: I only have 1 line in my HTML code:

Comment: <div class='bal-main-conatiner bal-table booking-table' id="tableGrid"></div>

Comment: Be careful, you are using the wrong `TAG`. Use `table` instead of `div` : `<table class='bal...</table>`. Also see : [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // styling stuff goes here
    // This function will be executed when the page is loaded
});
```

Comment: so something like this?

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(this).children("td:eq(15)").text() == "CREATED") {
    $(this).children("td").css('background', '#fffff9');
    $(this).children("td").css('color', '#000000');
  }
});

Comment: Yup, and also take a look at the answer from @DanteTheSmith

Comment: The code only checks the text on the first row of my table. How to loop every row in my table?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
   //what you wanna
}
```

Will trigger when dom elements are loaded.

If you are eager to do it ASAP, and don't wanna for all elements to load (because you might have tons of DOM elements and it takes long to load em all?) you can go for something like:

```
function myFunc() {
  if (document.getElementById('myElement')) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    setTimeout(myFunc, XNumber);
  }
}
```

Here the callback function in timeout is called every `XNumber` milliseconds and if element is in DOM it triggers the `// do stuff`

**But the main question is WHY do you wanna do it trough JS as soon as the table is loaded after the table is loaded and not have CSS ready before that so when the table is loaded the style is already there and applied to it?**

I would go with static CSS overrides for sure if it's the one-time thing. It's simple, readable, follows convention, separates concerns in the usual way and CSS should be loaded before elements appear anyway so it will affect your table immediately.

What would be downsides of the usual style in CSS approach? If you need to attach the style dynamically you can still go for `onload` and just add a class to the entire table.

Comment: I want to set it different value with the different background and font color

Comment: So, use CSS file (load it on your index page if it's single page app or appropriate page if it's not) and there overwrite the appropriate classes and / or HTML tags for the table. I can't see your table structure so I can't write you exact code but if it has normal table structure it could work with table > tr {background: red;} Just treat the table in DOM like you would regular elements, the fact it's generated not hardcoded doesn't matter. Use Dev console to find out what classes are applied to your table and use that in CSS selectors.